# r read data separator with 2 characters

Tags: r, fread, separator

I have a table (with more than 1 million rows) that is separated by '||' and inside one of the columns uses that symbol ('|'). I couldn't read it with fread from data.table because it only admits a length of 1 char, neither with read.table.
An example of the lines would be:

```
 1-Xxxxx||5804||CONTROL REMOTO 5804/5834 - xxxx||31/5/2018 03:00:00||CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? -(xxxx) (CIUDAD)||2
```

where the following was in only one field but it has the symbol '|':

```
 CALLE EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? - (xxxx) (CIUDAD)
```

The required split is:

```
field1= 1-Xxxxx
field2= 5804
field3= CONTROL REMOTO 5804/5834 - HONEYWELL
field4=31/5/2018 03:00:00
field5=CALLE EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? - () (CIUDAD EVITA )
field6= 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could just read it in as one column, then use e.g. `tidyr::separate` to split things up.

Comment: @Axeman, considering the size of the table, would it take less than 5 min to run? + what is the instruction to read in only one column? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can read in whole lines and then use regular expressions to split the lines. You have to add some column names to make it into a dataframe so I just used `a-f`, but replace with your own. You should also be able to replace `lines` with the path to your text file, here I'm just using literal data as an example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
line <- " 1-Xxxxx||5804||CONTROL REMOTO 5804/5834 - xxxx||31/5/2018 03:00:00||CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? -(xxxx) (CIUDAD)||2"
lines <- c(line, line)
line_list <- read_lines(lines) %>%
  str_split("\\|\\|") %>% 
  map(~set_names(., letters[1:6]))
bind_rows(!!!line_list)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   a       b     c              d         e                            f    
#>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>          <chr>     <chr>                        <chr>
#> 1 " 1-Xx… 5804  CONTROL REMOT… 31/5/201… CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99,… 2    
#> 2 " 1-Xx… 5804  CONTROL REMOT… 31/5/201… CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99,… 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: it's not getting the right result. It has to be the same column since  the word 'CALLE'

Comment: That is one column, everything from `CALLE` to `(CIUDAD)` is in one column. It just looks separate in the printing because of the amount of whitespace, but look at the column headers

Answer (score 0):

Read in your data in one column:

```
d <- data.table::fread(text = 
'1-Xxxxx||5804||CONTROL REMOTO 5804/5834 - xxxx||31/5/2018 03:00:00||CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? -(xxxx) (CIUDAD)||2
 1-Xxxxx||5804||CONTROL REMOTO 5804/5834 - xxxx||31/5/2018 03:00:00||CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? -(xxxx) (CIUDAD)||2', 
  sep = '', data.table = FALSE, header = FALSE)
```

Separate the columns:

```
tidyr::separate(d, V1, into = paste('V', 1:6), sep = '\\|\\|', covert = TRUE)
```

> ```
>       V 1  V 2                             V 3                V 4
> 1 1-Xxxxx 5804 CONTROL REMOTO 5804/5834 - xxxx 31/5/2018 03:00:00
> 2 1-Xxxxx 5804 CONTROL REMOTO 5804/5834 - xxxx 31/5/2018 03:00:00
>                                                                                          V 5 V 6
> 1 CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? -(xxxx) (CIUDAD)   2
> 2 CALLE     EL QUIYA CASA 99, MANZANA 99, - SECCION 8, CIRCUNSCRIPCION 4°|? -(xxxx) (CIUDAD)   2
> ```

Change `paste('V', 1:6)` to your actual column names.

(This approach is very similar to that of @CalumYou)